# Можно ли как-то брать пост из сообщества в ВК и отправлять его в группу? Vk-api python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть группа, посты в которой должны быть видны и обсуждены в чате каждый раз перекидывать получается не всегда можно ли как-то это автоматизировать с помощью VK-api для python?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете приложить пост к сообщению и отправить его с помощью метода [`messages.send`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send).

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


ACCESS_TOKEN = ...  # Подставьте свой
PEER_ID = ...       # Подставьте свой

vkSession = VkApi(token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
vk = vkSession.get_api()

vk.messages.send(
    peer_id=PEER_ID,
    message='Test message',
    attachment='wall-225666_403198',
    random_id=get_random_id(),
)
```

***Результат:***

[image: Пример сообщения]

---

Получить записи сообщества можно с помощью метода [`wall.get`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get).

Но обратите внимание на то, что этот метод нельзя вызвать с помощью ключа сообщества. Вам придётся создать сервисный ключ приложения или использовать учётные данные пользователя.

***Пример:***

```py
post = vk.wall.get(
    domain='b2band',
)['items'][0]
owner_id = post['owner_id']
media_id = post['id']

attachment = f'wall{owner_id}_{media_id}'
print(attachment)
```

***stdout:***

```html
wall-225666_403198
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не до конца. В примере вы показали, что сразу дается ссылка, а можно как-то автоматизировать этот процесс. к примеру при добавление в сообщество нового поста он автоматически отправлялся в группу?

Comment: @noname Да. Получаете посты из группы с помощью [wall.get](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get). Запоминайте `id` или `date` последнего поста. Через определённое время получаете посты ещё раз (обратите внимание, что есть параметр `count`), сравниваете `id` или `date` и обрабатываете новые записи. Как формировать `attachment` для отправки сообщения показано во 2-ом примере. Поэкспериментировать с запросами можно прямо из браузера на странице документации по методу.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли